# Excel Sumproduct ignore text issues

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula which works perfectly until I have a text value in column E.  When there is text in column E I get "#VALUE!"

=SUMPRODUCT(D7:D19,1/(1+E7:E19))

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Many thanks, Alan.

Comment: what do you want to do with it when it has text?

Comment: ignore that row ideally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=SUM(D7:D19*IFERROR(1/(1+E7:E19),0))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Many thanks, in my version I just needed to press enter.

Comment: yes, with the introduction of Dynamic Array Formula in Office 365, the need to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter is no longer needed.